# Generate a new string array where you combine each string from the first array with each string from the second array

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Solution {

    public static String[] combineAllStrings(String[] s1, String[] s2) {
        
        int a=s1.length*s2.length;
        String[] str1= new String[a];
        String str2=""; 
        for(int i=0;i<s1.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<s2.length;j++)
            {  
                 
                str2=s1[i]+s2[j];
               
                
             }
              
        }
        return str2;
       


    }
```

How can i store the result in an array and return it.

Hint: Use nested loops to iterate through the two given arrays and generate the combinations.

Hint: Initialize an output array and keep adding the combined strings in it. Finally, return this array.

Sample Input 1
["a", "c", "e"]

["b", "d", "f"]

Sample Output 1
["ab", "ad", "af", "cb", "cd", "cf", "eb", "ed", "ef"]

Explanation 1
We get "ab", "ad", "af" by combining a with b, d and f. Similarly all other elements are combined

Comment: Code formatting

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Just do this:

```
string[] first = new string[] { "a", "c", "e" };
string[] second = new string[] { "b", "d", "f" };

string[] output =
(
    from f in first
    from s in second
    select $"{f}{s}"
).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String[] combineAllStrings(String[] s1, String[] s2) {
        
       int a=s1.length*s2.length;
       String[] str1= new String[a];
       String str2=""; 
       for(int i=0;i<s1.length;i++)
       {
           for(int j=0;j<s2.length;j++)
           {  
               str2=s1[i]+s2[j];         
           }    
       }
       return str2;
    }
```

**Explanation:**

- Kine 1 and 2: You have created array of string `str1` and not using it instead you have created other variable `str2` which is wrong.
- line 8: you should have used `str1`; and use the `count` variable to store in further position as in forloop it will only work for outerloop

Your code will be:

```
public static String[] combineAllStrings(String[] s1, String[] s2) {

        int size=s1.length * s2.length;
        String []s3=new String[size];
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0; i<s1.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<s2.length; j++)
            {
                s3[count]=s1[i]+s2[j];
                count++;
            }
        }
        return s3;
    }
```